# Is it legal for the US private company to provide services depending on political party?

Tags: united-states, law, presidential-election, republican-party, democratic-party

[Read](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-election-survivalcamps-idUSKBN26R3IX) about US company "Fortitude Ranch", specializing on providing secure vaults, who would open it's "survival camps" at the election day.

**Can such company theoretically provide services according to political party?**

For example, that camp is exclusively for Republicans, and that one exclusively for Democrats. Would it be legal?

Comment: I'm sort of curious about enforcement. How would such a private company ever be able to determine my political affiliation if I didn't tell them? Or if I lied? Or claimed that it had changed just now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this 2016 article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2016/11/25/can-businesses-refuse-to-serve-or-employ-trump-supporters/) it's not prohibited by the federal government, but is prohibited by some state governments. Essentially it's the same protections as other characteristics such as race, gender, sexual orientation, etc. just with different states defining different characteristics.

Incidentally I think this is one of the weird things that both sides agree on contrary to the law - if for different reasons. A lot of Democrats (though I'm sure not all) seem to like they'd like to refuse service to any Republican/Trump supporter - while a lot of Republicans would argue a business has the right to chose who to do business with because of freedom of association.